Filter breaks topic and subscription name prefix in MassTransit
I use masstransit 8 + amazon sqs/sns, the app is running in Windows Docker container.
I've noticed that adding custom filter to consumers leads to the issue - name of topic and subscription lose their scope prefix. Though the queue itself has always the correct name (with prefix).
Steps to re-produce the issue:
Filter:
public sealed class CustomConsumeFilter<T> : IFilter<ConsumeContext<T>>  where T: class
{
    public async Task Send(ConsumeContext<T> context, IPipe<ConsumeContext<T>> next)
    {
        await next.Send(context);
    }

    public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
    {
        
    }
}

Consumer:
public class TestModelEventsConsumer : IConsumer<TestModel>
{
    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<TestModel> context)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

Masstransit initialization:
var builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder(args);

var configuration = builder.Configuration;

builder.Services
       .Configure<AmazonSqsTransportOptions>(configuration.GetSection("MassTransit:Transports:AmazonSqs"))
       .AddMassTransit(bus =>
       {
           bus.AddConsumer<TestModelEventsConsumer>();            

           bus.UsingAmazonSqs((context, sqs) =>
           {
               sqs.UseFilter(new CustomConsumeFilter<TestModel>()); // the issue is in this line

               var entityNameFormatter = new MessageNameFormatterEntityNameFormatter(new AmazonSqsMessageNameFormatter());

               var scope = "test-prefix-";
           
               sqs.MessageTopology.SetEntityNameFormatter(new PrefixEntityNameFormatter(entityNameFormatter, scope));

               sqs.ConfigureEndpoints(context, new KebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter(scope));
           });
       });

builder.Build().Run();

If I run the code with line "sqs.UseFilter" the following objects will be created:

Queue - test-prefix-test-model-events - correct (has prefix)
Topic - MyApplication_Services-TestModel - incorrect (no prefix)
Subscription ARN -
arn:aws:sns:eu-south-1:111111111111:MyApplication_Services-TestModel:66904f2a-fc68-4652-b038-ef2d6157b7c9 - incorrect (no prefix)

If I remove the line "sqs.UseFilter" the proper names will be created for objects:

Queue - test-prefix-test-model-events - correct (has prefix)
Topic - test-prefix-MyApplication_Services-TestModel - correct (has prefix)
Subscription ARN -
arn:aws:sns:eu-south-1:111111111111:test-prefix-MyApplication_Services-TestModel:b8eb1111-65ca-4833-9b3f-29df2b33a8c9 - correct (has prefix)

I didn't think that simple filter code affect tha name of objects. Setting the scope prefix "test-prefix-" I expect all objects (queue, topic, subscription) to have the prefix no matter if filter is using or not. Could you please advise if this a bug or not and how to resolve it ?
Thanks,
Evgeny.

Order matters, configure the topology settings before you add any filters or configure any endpoints.

Hi Chris. Yep, you're right, setting the proper order of initialization has resolved the issue. Thanks, much appreciated.
